# Docker: Mount volume on Windows host - Windows Container

Tags: windows, docker

I seem to be running the least supported combination of docker. Im running on a windows host machine and a windows container.

I want to mount C:\temp -> C:\temp
I have tried

docker run ... -v C:\temp:C:Temp
docker run ... -v C:/temp:C/:Temp
docker run ... -v //C:\temp://C/:Temp

Im supposed to go to docker settings "Shared Volumes". But that is not available for Windows containers

When I try to read from that directory in my application, the directory does not exist

Answer (score 0):

> I too was not able to mount C drive inside windows container to my
>   host OS C drive. The solutions given on mounting drives seems to be
>   related to Linux containers running on windows which is not expected
>   here.
>
> There is a workaround I did to access the host C drive from inside the
>   container and copy the files to a folder outside the container and
>   watch them in explorer(If that is the behavior which solves you
>   purpose). Below are the steps I performed.
>
> 1) docker exec -it container(name/id) powershell (open powershell
>   inside container)
>
> 2) net use X: \SERVER\Share  (X is the name of the network drive. You
>   can choose any name. SERVER is the IP address of your host machine.
>   Share is the folder name which is present in the host machine. In your
>   case it is c:\temp) **Example:** X:\ \XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\c$\temp You will be
>   prompted to enter your username and password
>
> 3) Once you have this setup, you can browse your network drive (X:).
>   Anything on your host temp folder will be accessible inside your
>   container. You can copy the files and folders to and from this network
>   drive and it would be visible in your C:\temp folder on your host
>   machine.

Hope this helps!